# NVidia Geforce GT240M Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS Driver & Graphic Problems

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am newbie to Ubuntu, installed it 1 week ago. I want to ask about my graphic driver GT240M NVidia. For example, when i tried to watch a video from mozilla firefox maybe in the Facebook, i get a squared screen in the video and too much delay like 15 sec video running like GTA V in my old laptop. And also when i tried to get in search in ubuntu, for instance, i wrote "oooooooooo" by pressing o simultaneously, i get the whole ooooooooo's in like 15 sec, if i am in windows i can wrote in 0.1 sec i think. If i put in a nutshell, i think i have graphic problems in my operating system and also i tried bumblebee, xedgers, nvidia-304, nvidia-313, nvidia-319, also the linux driver for nvidia's website. As a said, i am a newbie to Ubuntu, tried as many codes as i can from the websites, i set up clean Ubuntu like 30 times, so please i am begging you, how can i fix this problem ? What codes or what solution way that i can try here ? May be my CPU or RAM's does not work properly in Ubuntu(in Windows i can play World of Warcraft with smoothly) but the graphics in video is bad as i mentioned above. Thanks...

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT216M [GeForce GT 240M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 2034
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

And also i want to add some info too. I searched many forums and this site for solutions most of them say u have to install 190.42 driver file manually from ctrl+alt+F1, i tried this many times but i get this error;

The distribution-provided pre-install script failed. Continue?"

when i continued by pressing YES button, i get;

"ERROR: The kernel header file
'/lib/modules/3.16.0-30-generic/build/include/linux/version.h' does
not exist. The most likely reason for this is that the kernel source
files in '/lib/modules/3.16.0-30-generic/build' have not been
configured."

How can i fix this error to setup manually the 190.42 version of nvidia driver ? Please help...

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: Its look like a firm ware update is in need for the driver, have you tryed install the updated driver.

Answer (score 0):

i solved similar issue by installing proprietary drivers for NVidia in 
dash menu -> additional drivers.

there are plenty of them there, just try and see which works best for your GPU.

and if you have trouble locating or installing available nvidia drivers this [article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia) will help you.